# Отслеживание значений zoom'а страницы с помощью js

Tags: javascript

В каждом браузере есть функция zoom'а страницы (ctrl+scroll). Каким образом с помощью javascript получить значения zoom'a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете посмотреть соответствующий код [**здесь.**](http://htmldoodads.appspot.com/zoom-level.html) *Решение, хоть и работает везде, очень нетривиальное в реализации, т.к приходится использовать разные методы для разных браузеров.*